# Threejs: Is it possible to multiply vertices of ShapeGeometry?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I want to have more vertices for ShapeGeometry so that I can use bend modifier on custom shape I created. Unlike CubeGeometry you can set more segments but since I need a customized shape I have no choice but to use ShapeGeometry. Is this possible??

Comment: 'ShapeGeometry' being an one-sided polygonal geometry created from one or more path shapes; can't you add the additionnal vertices in the path?

Comment: Sorry but I'm still a newbie. I think you're right but how will I able to add more vertices to a Path. Tried googling it. Still no luck.

Comment: You can find a quick example in the doc [here](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shapegeo#Reference/Geometries/ShapeGeometry) ; or a live demo with complex shapes [here](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html)